# how to add time started field to celery results in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using Celery with MongoDB backend. I can see that it save the "date_done" field. I would also like for it to save the "date_start", but I can't seem to find a way how to do this. I was thinking of inheriting from the Mongodb [backend class](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/backends/mongodb.html#MongoBackend)  and overloading the methods that store the results in the database but I'm not sure that it's a good idea. Why isn't there a field like that?

```
{
  "_id" : "8b6f4ea0-4855-43a6-98f8-ae499f88b177",
  "status" : "SUCCESS",
  "children" : "[]",
  "traceback" : "null",
  "result" : "21",
  "date_done" : ISODate("2017-01-18T15:07:17.151Z")
}
```